# Unable to iterate over nested loop to calculate sum

Tags: python, numpy

I am unable find correct logic to find summation. I have binary_values and function as:

```py
binary_values =[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]

def f(x):
    m = np.matrix([0.5,-0.5, 0.3])
    w = m.transpose()
    Y = np.dot(x,w)
    return Y
f(x)
```

I have to find summation of

```
 1) f(1,0,0)-f(0,0,0))+(f(1,0,1)-f(0,0,1))+(f(1,1,0)-f(0,1,0))+(f(1,1,1)-f(0,1,1)) #this is for whenever "1" comes in 0th position inside nested loop.
        
 2) (f(0,1,0)-f(0,0,0))+(f(0,1,1)-f(0,0,1))+(f(1,1,0)-f(1,0,0))+(f(1,1,1)-f(1,0,1)) #this is for whenever "1" comes in 1st position
        
 3) (f(0,0,1)-f(0,0,0))+(f(0,1,1)-f(0,1,0))+(f(1,0,1)-f(1,0,0))+(f(1,1,1)-f(1,1,0)) #this is for whenever "1" comes in 2nd position
```

The code I tried:

```
sum = 0
for i in binary_values:
    for j in i:
        if(binary_values[i][0] == 1):
            sum = (f(1,0,0)-f(0,0,0))+(f(1,0,1)-f(0,0,1))+(f(1,1,0)- 
                   f(0,1,0))+(f(1,1,1)-f(0,1,1))
        elif(binary_values[i][1] == 1):
            sum = (f(0,1,0)-f(0,0,0))+(f(0,1,1)-f(0,0,1))+(f(1,1,0)- 
                   f(1,0,0))+(f(1,1,1)-f(1,0,1))
        elif(binary_values[i][2] == 1):
            sum = (f(0,0,1)-f(0,0,0))+(f(0,1,1)-f(0,1,0))+(f(1,0,1)- 
                   f(1,0,0))+(f(1,1,1)-f(1,1,0))
        else:
            print("Error")
print(sum)
```

Please suggest me the better logic

Comment: Although I don't fully understand your question, it seems that the problem is `binary_values[i][0] == 1`, where you used `i` as a index (it's a list in `binary_values`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you described is because you do:

```
for i in binary _values # Will put the value of i to a inner list item like [0,1,1]
```

then you do:

```
for j in i # makes j a value inside the inner list like
           # 0 - first iteration ,  1 - second iteration, 1 - third iteration
```

and then you try to use **i** as a position variable for binary_values, but this will not work because **i** will contain a part of the binary_values list as described.

Does the following code do what you wanted? As well i think if you want to sum up all of them, you will need the += operator to add up the sums... But feel free to describe your problem further and i will edit my answer as well.

Edit Answer (see comments):

```
import numpy as np

binary_values = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]

def f(x):
    m =np.matrix([0.5,-0.5, 0.3])
    w = m.transpose()
    Y = np.dot(x,w)
    return Y[0,0]

sums = {"sum1":0,"sum2":0,"sum3":0,"fullsum1":0,"fullsum2":0,"fullsum3":0,"allsum":0}

for i in binary_values:
    if(i[0] == 1):
        sums["sum1"] = (f([1,0,0])-f([0,0,0]))+(f([1,0,1])-f([0,0,1]))+(f([1,1,0])-f([0,1,0]))+(f([1,1,1])-f([0,1,1]))
    if(i[1] == 1):
        sums["sum2"] = (f([0,1,0])-f([0,0,0]))+(f([0,1,1])-f([0,0,1]))+(f([1,1,0])-f([1,0,0]))+(f([1,1,1])-f([1,0,1]))
    if(i[2] == 1):
        sums["sum3"] = (f([0,0,1])-f([0,0,0]))+(f([0,1,1])-f([0,1,0]))+(f([1,0,1])-f([1,0,0]))+(f([1,1,1])-f([1,1,0]))

    sums["fullsum1"] += sums["sum1"]
    sums["fullsum2"] += sums["sum2"]
    sums["fullsum3"] += sums["sum3"]

    sums["allsum"] += sums["sum1"] + sums["sum2"] + sums["sum3"]

    print("For:", i)
    print(f" Result Sum i[1] = %8.2f ; Result Sum i[2] = %8.2f ; Result Sum i[3] = %8.2f" % (sums["sum1"],sums["sum2"],sums["sum3"]))
    print(f"     Sum of i[1] = %8.2f ;     Sum of i[2] = %8.2f ;     Sum of i[3] = %8.2f" % (sums["fullsum1"],sums["fullsum2"],sums["fullsum3"]))
    print(f"      All sum up = %8.2f" % (sums["allsum"]))
    print()

print("Final:")
print(f"Result Sum i[1] = %8.2f ; Result Sum i[2] = %8.2f ; Result Sum i[3] = %8.2f" % (sums["sum1"],sums["sum2"],sums["sum3"]))
print(f"    Sum of i[1] = %8.2f ;     Sum of i[2] = %8.2f ;     Sum of i[3] = %8.2f" % (sums["fullsum1"],sums["fullsum2"],sums["fullsum3"]))
print(f"     All sum up = %8.2f" % (sums["allsum"]))
```

Edit:
There was another mistake, i forget to add to my answer.

In your code you tried to call the function f(x) with 3 values like (1,0,0), but the argument list contains takes only a single value for x. So you could the three values into a single list to pass them in this way... Otherwise it will end up into a:

```
TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Comment: I got output as:Error
0
[[1.2]]
[[-0.8]]
[[-2.8]]
[[-0.8]]
[[1.2]]
[[3.2]]
[[5.2]], when I place print inside of loop, because I need sum for, i[0],i[1],i[2]

Comment: Okay can you exactly describe how the output will look like? So you need the sum for all three cases? In this case the if elif would be false. Or do you want three different sums?

Comment: I need three different sums.

Comment: Okay, i updated my solution. Can you try this? This will show you all kinds of sums you can potentialy mean. Otherwise it would be eventually helpful, if you describe your general problem, why you have to sum up something like this. The current description is kind of vague. ^^